# Adding a new column to a data frame using numbers to show order of date (oldest to most recent)

Tags: r

I currently have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   ID        DOB
1 535 1994-03-06
2 429 2001-01-08
3 535 1999-06-12
4 535 2001-04-06
5 111 1994-08-08
6 429 1995-09-20
```

Each of the rows represent different people, and each of the IDs indicate the families of each person.

What I am wanting is this:

```
   ID        DOB birthOrder
1 111 1994-08-08          1
2 429 1995-09-20          1
3 429 2001-01-08          2
4 535 1994-03-06          1
5 535 1999-06-12          2
6 535 2001-04-06          3
```

I would like the new `birthOrder` column to show the order of birth of each person within the family (from oldest to youngest). Which function would I use for this?

Another complication to this code would be the presence of twins. If there were twins in the data frame, I'd want the result data frame to look like so:

```
   ID        DOB birthOrder
1 111 1994-08-08          1
2 429 1995-09-20          1
3 429 2001-01-08          2
4 429 2001-01-08          2
5 535 1994-03-06          1
6 535 1999-06-12          2
7 535 2001-04-06          3`
```

Could I use the `rank` function from `dplyr` to create this new variable?

Comment: We can use `dense_rank`, `df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(birthorder = dense_rank(DOB))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `row_number()` after grouping by 'ID'. As the rows needs to be ordered by 'DOB', `arrange` by the 'DOB' after converting to `Date` class

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    arrange(ID, as.Date(DOB)) %>% 
    mutate(birthOrder = row_number())
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID DOB        birthOrder
#  <int> <chr>           <int>
#1   111 1994-08-08          1
#2   429 1995-09-20          1
#3   429 2001-01-08          2
#4   535 1994-03-06          1
#5   535 1999-06-12          2
#6   535 2001-04-06          3
```

---

Or for the second case, we can use `match`

```
df2 %>%
   arrange(ID, as.Date(DOB)) %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(birthOrder = match(DOB, unique(DOB)))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID DOB        birthOrder
#  <int> <chr>           <int>
#1   111 1994-08-08          1
#2   429 1995-09-20          1
#3   429 2001-01-08          2
#4   429 2001-01-08          2
#5   535 1994-03-06          1
#6   535 1999-06-12          2
#7   535 2001-04-06          3
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but my birthOrder column doesn't give me values per birth order per ID, but it comes out as "1,2,3,3,4,5,6"

Comment: @Dieu94  Is it for the same data you showed?  The data I used is `df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(111L, 429L, 429L, 429L, 535L, 535L, 535L
), DOB = c("1994-08-08", "1995-09-20", "2001-01-08", "2001-01-08", 
"1994-03-06", "1999-06-12", "2001-04-06")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Yes - for the original data frame with only the ID and DOB column. The data I used was `> ID <- c(111, 429, 429,429, 535, 535,535)
> DOB <- as.Date(c('8/8/1994','20/09/1995', '8/1/2001','8/1/2001','6/3/1994',  '12/6/1999', '6/4/2001' ), "%d/%m/%Y")
> birthOrder <-c(1,1,2,2,1,2,3)
> newdata<-data.frame(ID, DOB, birthOrder) For your first suggestion, I get this error: `Error: row_number() should only be called in a data context` and the second option returns the birth order value for the group as a whole, but not with ID - thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @Dieu94 I don't have an issue in the data you shared as well `newdata %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
     arrange(ID, as.Date(DOB)) %>% 
     mutate(birthOrder = row_number()) %>% pull(birthOrder)
#[1] 1 1 2 3 1 2 3`

Comment: hmm.. what does `Error: row_number() should only be called in a data context` mean?

Comment: @Dieu94  Can you tell me your `dplyr` version.  I used `‘0.8.0.1’`.  Also, if there is any environment issue, it may be better to start on a fresh session

Comment: I've started a fresh session and used your data and code but I still end up with 'ID DOB birthOrder <int> <chr> <int> 1 111 1994-08-08 1 2 429 1995-09-20 2 3 429 2001-01-08 3 4 429 2001-01-08 3 5 535 1994-03-06 4 6 535 1999-06-12 5 7 535 2001-04-06 6' no idea why!

Comment: I've work it out. It doesn't load when I've also got plyr loaded! Thank you!!