# How to convert this vertical dataset to horizontal dataset?

Tags: r, transpose, data-handling

I wanna change this data set:

```
        id PTMIINDT PTMIINTM DGOTDIAG DGOTDGGB
1: ys00000001 20160101      614     R060        1
2: ys00000002 20160101      640    S0090        1
3: ys00000002 20160101      640     A090        2
4: ys00000003 20160101      959      R42        1
5: ys00000007 20160101     1111    S0600        1
6: ys00000008 20160101     1253     R558        1
```

to this dataset:

```
         id     PTMIINDT PTMIINTM DGOTDIAG01 DGOTDGGB01 DGOTDIAG02  DGOTDGGB02
1 ys00000001      20160101     614      R060          1         NA          NA
2 ys00000002      20160101     640     S0090          1       A090           2
.     .               .         .
.     .               .         .
.     .               .         .
```

like this.

I tried to make this data set with mutate function. but it didn't work well.
How can I change the dataset like this?

```
ba<-n6 %>% group_by(id,PTMIINDT,PTMIINTM) %>% 
  mutate(DGOTDIAG01=DGOTDIAG, DGOTDIAG02=DGOTDIAG, DGOTDGGB01=DGOTDGGB,DGOTDGGB02=DGOTDGGB)


ba<-n6 %>% group_by(id,PTMIINDT,PTMIINTM) %>% 
  mutate(DGOTDIAG01=DGOTDIAG, DGOTDIAG02=DGOTDIAG, DGOTDGGB01=DGOTDGGB,DGOTDGGB02=DGOTDGGB)

         id     PTMIINDT PTMIINTM DGOTDIAG01 DGOTDGGB01 DGOTDIAG02  DGOTDGGB02
1 ys00000001      20160101     614      R060          1         NA          NA
2 ys00000002      20160101     640     S0090          1       A090           2
.     .               .         .
.     .               .         .
.     .               .         .
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table::dcast()` this can be done using the following one-liner.

```
library(data.table)
```

**sample data**

```
dt <- data.table::fread("id PTMIINDT PTMIINTM DGOTDIAG DGOTDGGB
ys00000001 20160101      614     R060        1
ys00000002 20160101      640    S0090        1
ys00000002 20160101      640     A090        2
ys00000003 20160101      959      R42        1
ys00000007 20160101     1111    S0600        1
ys00000008 20160101     1253     R558        1")
```

**code**

```
data.table::dcast( dt, id + PTMIINDT + PTMIINTM ~ DGOTDGGB, value.var = c("DGOTDIAG", "DGOTDGGB") )
```

**output**

```
#            id PTMIINDT PTMIINTM DGOTDIAG_1 DGOTDIAG_2 DGOTDGGB.1_1 DGOTDGGB.1_2
# 1: ys00000001 20160101      614       R060       <NA>            1           NA
# 2: ys00000002 20160101      640      S0090       A090            1            2
# 3: ys00000003 20160101      959        R42       <NA>            1           NA
# 4: ys00000007 20160101     1111      S0600       <NA>            1           NA
# 5: ys00000008 20160101     1253       R558       <NA>            1           NA
```

Answer (score 0):

The development version of `tidyr` features a new verb, `pivot_wider` which is better suited to this task.

https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/pivot.html

In the meantime, you can gather, convert, and spread:

```
n6 %>%
  gather(column, value, -c(id, PTMIINDT, PTMIINTM)) %>%
  group_by(id, PTMIINDT, PTMIINTM) %>%
  mutate(column = paste0(column, 
                         stringr::str_pad(row_number(), width = 2, pad = 0))) %>%
  spread(column, value)

# A tibble: 5 x 8
# Groups:   id, PTMIINDT, PTMIINTM [5]
  id         PTMIINDT PTMIINTM DGOTDGGB02 DGOTDGGB03 DGOTDGGB04 DGOTDIAG01 DGOTDIAG02
  <chr>         <int>    <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1 ys00000001 20160101      614 1          NA         NA         R060       NA        
2 ys00000002 20160101      640 NA         1          2          S0090      A090      
3 ys00000003 20160101      959 1          NA         NA         R42        NA        
4 ys00000007 20160101     1111 1          NA         NA         S0600      NA        
5 ys00000008 20160101     1253 1          NA         NA         R558       NA
```

Comment: thanks for comment. but i got an error like this. what should i do on this error? 

> aa<-n6 %>%
+   gather(column, value, -c(id, PTMIINDT, PTMIINTM)) %>%
+   group_by(id, PTMIINDT, PTMIINTM) %>%
+   mutate(column = paste0(column, 
+                          str_pad(row_number(), width = 2, pad = 0))) %>%
+   spread(column, value)
Error in str_pad(row_number(), width = 2, pad = 0) : 
  could not find function "str_pad"

Comment: sorry about that, should have written `stringr::str_pad` in it's place. edited above.

Comment: thanks for reply. i tried. but i got this messege again..

> aa<-n6 %>%
+   gather(column, value, -c(id, PTMIINDT, PTMIINTM)) %>%
+   group_by(id, PTMIINDT, PTMIINTM) %>%
+   mutate(column = paste0(column, 
+                          stringr::str_pad(row_number(), width = 2, pad = 0))) %>%
+   spread(column, value)
Error: row_number() should only be called in a data context
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Answer (score 0):

With the last version of `tidyr` (`1.0.0`, already on CRAN):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
n6 %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(sbs = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = sbs, values_from = c(DGOTDIAG,DGOTDGGB))

# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Groups:   id [5]
  id         PTMIINDT PTMIINTM DGOTDIAG_1 DGOTDIAG_2 DGOTDGGB_1 DGOTDGGB_2
  <fct>         <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>      <fct>           <dbl>      <dbl>
1 ys00000001 20160101      614 R060       NA                  1         NA
2 ys00000002 20160101      640 S0090      A090                1          2
3 ys00000003 20160101      959 R42        NA                  1         NA
4 ys00000007 20160101     1111 S0600      NA                  1         NA
5 ys00000008 20160101     1253 R558       NA                  1         NA
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. but i got an error like this. 

Error in get(nm, envir = fn, mode = "function") : 
  object 'pivot_wider' of mode 'function' was not found

what should i do?

Comment: Have you installed development version of `tidyr`? It seems that you do not have the function loaded.

Comment: yapp! i installed the latest version of tidyr. 
Is it 0.8.3 version right?!

Comment: No, you should use development version in github. Instruction `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")` should install it.

Comment: I tried ! but still it has some problems.

ac<-n6 %>% 
+   group_by(id) %>% 
+   mutate(sbs = row_number()) %>% 
+   tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = sbs, values_from = c(DGOTDIAG,DGOTDGGB))
Error: row_number() should only be called in a data context

what should i do? thanks

Comment: I don't know. I didn't have that problem. What object is n6? Is it a data frame? Could you specify in the question how did you define/build n6? Maybe is a problem of an old version of `dplyr` (I have installed `0.8.3`)

Comment: Looking at the comments of the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55506865/adding-a-new-column-to-a-data-frame-using-numbers-to-show-order-of-date-oldest), it could be an issue due to have the package `plyr` loaded. If this is the case, you may unload `plyr` or write `dplyr::mutate` instead of `mutate`.